# VSCode Angular Debugging Working but why do I need the "-host=127.0.0.1" parameter?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I was struggling to get Angular debugging in VSCode to work. I'm using Angular 15 with VSCode 1.74 and Chrome (build 109) on Windows 11. I followed the vscode Angular recipe

[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/main/Angular-CLI](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

but when I started the debugger I was receiving a bunch of errors in the Debug Console and breakpoints wouldn't bind:

> Could not read source map for http://localhost:4200/runtime.js:
> Unexpected 503 response from http://127.0.0.1:4200/runtime.js.map:
> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200 WARNING: Processing source-maps of
> http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js took longer than 5795.8976 ms so we
> continued execution without waiting for all the breakpoints for the
> script to be set.Could not read source map for
> http://localhost:4200/main.js: Unexpected 503 response from
> http://127.0.0.1:4200/main.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200
> ....

Not sure where I read it but I finally added "--host=127.0.0.1" to the start script in package.json

```
"name": "my-first-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --host=127.0.0.1",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

....

Then everything works. I don't get the source map errors and I can set breakpoints after the application launches (URL in my browser is localhost:4200). I have researched this parameter but I don't understand why this makes a difference. Can anyone explain?

I tried removing this parameter just to make certain and all the issues returned.